# how to set the authentication without magic number botframeworkV4

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

I have read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth). The magic code has been eliminated. I test it using [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication). But it still needs the magic code? I used webchat to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bot sample is fine. But this authentication feature currently only work if you have DirectLine enabled and are using a DirectLine secret. You can follow [this blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/01/using-webchat-with-azure-bot-services-authentication/).

Comment: Is it possible to eliminate the magic code, if using teams or other channel?

Comment: @Jeff_hu Currently the answer is no. This is stated on the official blog.

Comment: You can disable magic code from your bot emulator settings.
Go to bot emulator settings and uncheck the "use sign-in verification code .." option.